# Import excel with nested cells (headers) and parse it to json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I need to import an excel file, get the json and draw the same table in my form.

I have used XLSX and `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, {header: 1, defval: ''})` , but the problem is in merged cells.

Im trying to parse this excel file

[image]

And receiving json data in this form:

```
[
    ["Item","Index","Params","",""],
    ["","","Value","Style",""],
    ["", "","","Color","Font"],
    ["abc",1,999,"red","bold"],
    ["cas",2,312,"yellow","italic"]
]
```

I understand that empty string means that the cell is merged, but I can't understand which cell was merged (neighboring, top, both).

Are there any libraries/other solutions to my problem?

in output i want something like this

```
 [
   {title: 'Item'},
   {title: 'Index'},
   {title: 'Params',childrens: [
      {title: 'Value'},
      {title: 'Style', childrens: [
          {title: 'Color'},
          {title: 'Font'}
        ]
      },
     ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: What output do you need?

Comment: @James added to the end of the question (just header with merged cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more straightforward way to do this using SheetJS (or otherwise).

I have hardcoded the length of the headers (`let headerLength = 3;`).  Maybe you can figure out what that value should be some other way.

The code below first "flattens" the headers to a single row, using dots to concatenate the strings.  Then I use the flattened headers to build your header structure.

```js
const sheet = [
    ["Item","Index","Params","",""],
    ["","","Value","Style",""],
    ["", "","","Color","Font"],
    ["abc",1,999,"red","bold"],
    ["cas",2,312,"yellow","italic"]
];
let headerLength = 3;

let headers = sheet.slice(0, headerLength);

let flatHeaders = headers.reduce((acc, row, i, rows) => {
  row.forEach((el, j) => {
    if (!el) {
      if (rows[i + 1]?.[j]) {
        if (!acc[j]) {
          if (acc[j - 1]) {
            acc[j] = acc[j - 1];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (acc[j]) {
        acc[j] += "." + el;
      } else {
        acc[j] = el;
      }
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log("flat headers", flatHeaders);

//flat headers with rest of data
//let flatData = [flatHeaders].concat(sheet.slice(headerLength));
//console.log("flat data", flatData);

let headerStructure = flatHeaders.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.includes(".")) {
    let currentArr = acc;
    el.split(".").forEach((part, i, arr) => {
      let dest = currentArr.find(h => h.title === part);
      if (!dest) {
        dest = {title: part};
        currentArr.push(dest);
      }
      if (i < arr.length - 1) {
        if (!dest.children) {
          dest.children = [];
        }
        currentArr = dest.children;
      }
    });
  } else {
    acc.push({title: el});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log("structured headers", headerStructure);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! 
I did found away to dynamically mark merged cell